# Back button in Android traverses all the stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

On the home screen there are two links to navigate to 'Screen A' & 'Screen B'. The react navigation code is below. In Android, the user navigates from Home -> Screen A and later navigates to Home screen via a back button in the app (navigation.goBack()). **The problem:** now the user navigates from Home -> Screen B. Now from Screen B when the mobile's BACK button is pressed the user is redirected to Screen A and again when the mobile's BACK button is pressed the user is redirected to Home. The correct navigation should be Screen B -> Home.

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    drawerContent={(props) => (
      <CustomDrawerContent drawerItems={drawerItemsMain} {...props} />
    )}
  >
    {drawerItemsMain.map((item) =>
      item.routes.map((route) => (
        <Drawer.Screen
          key={route.routeName}
          name={route.routeName}
          component={route.component}
        />
      ))
    )}
    <Drawer.Screen name="StackScreens" component={StackScreensNavigator} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;

const StackScreensNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function StackScreensNavigator() {
  return (
    <StackScreensNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <StackScreensNavigator.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
      <StackScreensNavigator.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
    </StackScreensNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in here is you take `StackScreensNavigator` to named both `StackNavigator` and `Drawer.Screen` 's component. You should change name one of them:

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function StackScreensNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: I had to change the Drawer.Navigation to Stack.Navigation as well, then it worked. But now I don't have the hamburger menu in ScreenA & ScreenB.

Comment: `Drawer navigation` not display hamburger menu in default. If you want to use it, you have to create yourself